# Perl: Value of global variable not getting updated when changed in child

Tags: perl, fork

**Code Snippet:**

```
    my $kill=0;
    my @array1 = ("abc", "def","ghi");
    &runSmokesAndMonitor;
    
    sub runSmokesAndMonitor {
        foreach my $smokeTestVarDirName (@array1) {
             if ($pid =fork()) {
                 print "parent\n";  ### Have some other action items as well here in parent 
             }
             else {
                 $kill++;
                 print "Value of kill is $kill\n";
                 exit 0;
             }
        }
    }
```

Here, I am getting output:

```
parent
Value of kill is 1
parent
Value of kill is 1
parent
Value of kill is 1
```

**Required/Expected:** (As $kill is global variable, so values of $kill must have updated wherever new value would have assigned)

```
parent
Value of kill is 1
parent
Value of kill is 2
parent
Value of kill is 3
parent
```

Why is the output not as expected, and how can i achieve it?

Comment: Parallel::ForkManager could be useful in many ways here, including the fact that it provides a mechanism for sending data back to the parent. /// Without P::FM, a simple solution would be to exit 1 when you want kill updated, and exit 0 when you don't.

Comment: What are you actually trying to count? There are various ways that a parent process can keep track of its children and check if a process is alive.

Comment: @briandfoy, I am not counting simply as it is looking in the code. This is just for the community purpose that I have shortened the code. The count is happening in some other way based on some conditions.

Comment: @ikegami, "exit 1" thing is not working

Comment: I presume you mean your code for updating $kill in the parent when exit 1 is used doesn't work. And??

Comment: @ikegami, I mean $kill++ is there in child itself, and exit 1 is also in child (as mentioned in code above), and $kil is not updating as expected.

Comment: Re "*mean $kill++ is there in child itself*", Why? You already know that won't work. You've already been told why that won't work.

Answer (score 4):

A child created by fork is a new process with its own address space. Global variables are per process only, not global per user or per system or even global between all instances of a software running in the world. That's why changes to a global variable are only reflected in the current process.

If you need to share information between processes you need IPC (inter process communication), i.e. things like sockets, pipes, shared memory etc - see [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc) for more. There are ways to make sharing variables across processes easier, like [IPC::Shareable](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Shareable).